# What do parenthesis do in Python?

Tags: python

So, as a newbie in `Python`, I am trying to understand it with the use of some examples. I'd like to understand it better, so I have made this:

```
class MyClass(object):
     i = 123
     def hot(self):
         self.i = 345
         return self.i

a = MyClass()
print a.hot()
```

**1)** Is it correct when I state that *hot* is a `method` and therefore needs to be printed like `a.hot()`, so with the parentheses in the end?

Because, I could do this too:

```
class MyClass2(object):
     i = 123
     def __init__(self):
         self.i = 345

a = MyClass2()
print a.i
```

And it both would give me 345.

**2)** What is the reason I am not using parentheses here? Is it because `MyClass2` has not a method with a specific name (hence, it's `__init__`) so this makes it an entirely different method type?

I would really love some help, because it's quite confusing sometimes. I am trying to understand how `__init__` and `hot` differ, if they are both are seen as methods in Python. Why aren't we using parenthesis for both, then?

**3)** Also, I guess `return` is only used when having a method with a real name (like hot), is that correct?

Comment: `()` *calls* a function. If it's not a function, it doesn't need to be (can't be) called.

Comment: Most importantly, _read the documentation_! All of this becomes clear after you do so.

Comment: Guys, I have checked the documentation and the questions here. The things is: it just confuses me when I don't get a specific answer to my questions. I have closure when experts look to my question and confirm what I ask / say (if correct) or point me in the right direction. I just want a clear answer, instead of having to guess that I am probably right. That's why I am asking it.

Comment: `a.hot` is a function, so you need to call it if you want its `return`ed value. `a.i` is an integer whose value you can access just as is. `__init__` has nothing to do with the second case at all, except that it gets called automatically when `MyClass2` is instantiated.

Comment: Hi deceze, thank you for your answer. Makes a bit more sense now. I thought hot was a method, because it's a function that is in a class. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: No, that's correct; a function as property of an object is more specifically called a method.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you very much!